# Can I get Ruby's method_missing behavior in typescript?

Tags: typescript, method-missing

If a class does not implement a method, I want to handle the error raised and inject my own code, using the method name.

For example:

```
class Foo {
    def method_missing(methodName) {
        console.log(`${methodName} was called`);
    }
}

let foo = new Foo();
foo.bar(); // should print 'bar was called' in the console
```

In ruby, there is a method called `method_missing` on every class that provides this behavior. Can we get this in typescript, and how?

Answer (score 0):

No, TypeScript cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit more troublesome for TypeScript or JavaScript to have this, because in their world a method is just an Object attribute that holds a function reference instead of Ruby's way where the entire interface of an object consists of methods.

It might however be possible to implement something like this using a `Proxy` class. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) describes it as follows:

> The Proxy object allows you to create an object that can be used in
> place of the original object, but which may redefine fundamental
> Object operations like getting, setting, and defining properties.
> Proxy objects are commonly used to log property accesses, validate,
> format, or sanitize inputs, and so on.

I've heard that this feature supposedly could not be transpiled down to ECMAScript 5 platforms. I have not confirmed this yet, but better test this, so that you don't lock yourself out of platforms that are mandatory for you by considering this feature.